# Different position incremental behaviour of Synonym Filter

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene

My use case is to search for `edge_ngrams` with `synonym` support where the tokens to match should be in sequence.

While trying out the analysis, I observed 2 different behaviour of the filter chain with respect to position increments.

1. With filter-chain as `lowercase, synonym` there is no position increment due to `SynonymFilter`
2. With filter-chain as `lowercase, edge_ngram, synonym` there is position increment due to `SynonymFilter`

Here are the queries I'm running for each case:

**Case 1. No position increment**

```
PUT synonym_test
{
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "by_smart": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "custom_synonym"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "custom_synonym": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "begin => start"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


GET synonym_test/_analyze
{
  "text": "begin working",
  "analyzer": "by_smart"
}
```

*Outputs :*

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "start",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "SYNONYM",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "working",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

**Case 2. Position increment**

```
PUT synonym_test
{
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "by_smart": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "custom_edge_ngram",
            "custom_synonym"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "custom_synonym": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "begin => start"
          ]
        },
        "custom_edge_ngram": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": "2",
          "max_gram": "60"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

GET synonym_test/_analyze
{
  "text": "begin working",
  "analyzer": "by_smart"
}
```

*Outputs :*

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "be",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "beg",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "begi",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "start",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "SYNONYM",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "wo",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "wor",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "work",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "worki",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "workin",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "working",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice how in *Case1* the token `begin` and `start` when replaced have the same position and there is no position increment. However in *Case 2*, when `begin` token is replaced by `start` the position got incremented for the subsequent token stream.

**Now here are my questions :**

1. Why is it not happening in *Case 1* and only happening in *Case 2* ?
2. The main issue that this is causing is when the input query is `begi wor` with `match_phrase` query (and default `slop` as `0`) it doesn't matches `begin work`.
   Which is happening since `begi` and `wor` are 2 positions away. Any suggestions on how can I achieve this behaviour without impacting my use case ?

I'm using ElasticSearch version `5.6.8` having lucene version `6.6.1`.

I've read several documentation links and articles but I couldn't find any proper one explaining why is this happening and is there some settings to get my desired behaviour.